# Template error in p-DataTable in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using the template tag inside `p-column` in p-datatable for doing some custom formatting like this :

```
<p-column field="forexDate" header="frx Date" [sortable]="true" >
    <template  let-col let-xInDownData ="rowData" pTemplate="body" >
    {{xInDownData.forexDate | date}}
    </template>  
</p-column>
```

But after running this, I am getting this error :

`Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "template"`

Note : I am using Angular 2.x.x

Can some one please let me know where I am going wrong with this ?

Comment: Any ideas ? Anybody ?

Comment: You need to change it as <ng-template>

Comment: @Vignesh  Wrong . Angular 2 does not use ng-template but template syntax . Angular 4 uses ng-template .

Comment: Have you fixed the issue